# Object calling a method in turn calling another in c++

Tags: c++

While doing reverse engineering of a code in c++ I found some part of the code which am not getting at all. I am new to c++ and the way am asking the question may not be correct as I dont know how to ask this specific question please excuse me for the same. Let me elaborate little bit on this.
I encountered something like this in code.

```
obj.function_1( ).function_2(argument)
```

and in some places I found like

```
function_1( ).function_2(argument)
```

`function_1()` and `function_2( )` are of different classes.  Can anybody please help me on this what the above two lines means.

Comment: Perhaps a different object is returned from the function? You should post the associated code

Comment: Read `function_1` (or at least it's declaration) and note the return type. Then, get a book or something - asking questions about everything you see is a poor way to learn a language, and a really poor use of everyone elses' time.

Answer (score 1):

`obj.function_1()` will return an object that has a member function called `function_2`.

This will be the same for `function_1().function_2(argument)`.

Comment: Or, it could return a reference to a non-temporary member object.

Answer (score 1):

It simply invokes `function_2(argument)` of the return value of `function_1()`.
You could also write this as

```
ObjA obja;
ObjB objb = obja.function_1();
objb.function_2(argument);
```

The same works with your second example:

```
ObjB objb = function_1();
objb.function_2(argument);
```

It is written in your code differently in order no to worry about that temporary variable, probably because it is not needed later on.

Comment: Except that your examples copy by value, which _may_ (depending on the return type) change behaviour significantly.

Comment: In OP's example we are discarding the temporary object immediately. Let's assume `function_2(argument)` would be a setter for objects of `ObjB`. Imho in OP's example the newly set value cannot be used anywhere. In my example one could use the changed object. Of course I assumed that `ObjB(const ObjB&)` and `ObjB& operator=(const ObjB&)` are implemented properly. So, I don't get that significant behaviour change. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If `function_1` returns a reference to an object owned by `obja`, you just used a _local copy of that object_, rather than `obja`'s instance. So, if you mutated the object, your change is lost. If the reference is to the base type of a polymorphic object, you additionally sliced it, and if `function_2` is virtual you potentially invoked a different overload than intended.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.function_1( ).function_2(argument)`
-> call `function_1( )` of `obj`, then call `function_2(argument)` for the return value of `obj.function_1( )`

`function_1( ).function_2(argument)`
-> call `function_1( )` (in global or in the class where this code is), then all `function_2(argument)` for the return value of `function_1( )`

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.function_1( ).function_2(argument)
```

means that `obj` has `function_1()` and the return type (probably an object of some type) of `function_1()` has `function_2()` which takes `argument` as a parameter.

Similarly,

```
function_1( ).function_2(argument)
```

means that `function_1()` is valid to be called in the current scope, and the return type (probably an object of some type) of `function_1()` has `function_2()` which takes `argument` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> ... Can anybody please help me on this what the above two lines means.

No. That depends on exactly what the objects and functions *are*, and you haven't shown that. There's no way to tell what the code does, unless you can *see all the code*.

For example, all these scenarios are different:

1. obj has type `std::vector<int>`, `function_1 == std::vector<int>::rbegin` and `function_2 == std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator::operator[]`

   Here, the last line

   ```
   std::vector<int> obj = { 1, 2 };
   obj.rbegin().operator[](0);
   ```

   gives an `int&` reference to the last element of the vector (and doesn't change anything)
2. obj has type `std::vector<std::complex<double>>`, `function_1 == std::vector<std::complex<double>>::front` and `function_2 == std::complex<double>::operator+=`

   ```
   std::vector<std::complex<double>> obj = {{1,1}, {-1,-1}};
   obj.front().operator+=(-1);
   ```

   subtracts 1 from the real part of the first complex element, leaving `{0,1}`=*i* as the first element instead of `{1,1}`=*1+i*.
3. obj has type `MyBigRDBMS`, `function_1 == GetTables` (returning a proxy for the collection of all tables in our DB), and `function_2 == Drop`

   ```
   obj.GetAllTables.Drop();
   ```

   drops all tables from our DB.